# Wicket pagestore results wrong page

Tags: session, wicket, hazelcast

I have a problem with my web application with wicket. I am using wicket 6.14. I can't say exactly what the problem is, but I can describe the problem.

I am using a self written pagestore, which uses hazelcast. The pages are stored in the wicket default sessioncache and also in the hazelcast store. If I restart my webserver, the pages are stored from hazelcast, because I don't have anything in my session cache on my webserver anymore.

I go through my flow on my web application the following way:

1. Go to my page and filling my form
2. I go further and go to page 3
3. I restart my webserver, and click continue to follow to page 4. The page is stored from hazelcase and everything seems to work.
4. I fill some fields and click continue to page 5
5. I fill another form and click continue, "here I get a Validation error"

I suppose the following, because I tested and debugged through my application. After the restart of my webserver wicket is storing the wrong pages in the session cache. At the 5th page a wrong page is stored from sessioncache and the expected page is a different page then I want. On another position of my application I get a "component has been removed from page" error. Why I think that wicket is storing the wrong page in the sessioncache ? Because after the restart of my web application the ids of my pages changes. I have usually urls like: www.mysite.de/flow?1

The 1 is the pageid. Usually I get urls like www.mysite.de/flow?1 for 1st page. www.mysite.de/flow?2 for 2nd page and so on. After restarting my webserver the ids of my url dont change and I think that at this point the pages are stored wrongly into the session cache.

I am sorry, that I dont have code here. But it will help me alot if someone can describe how pagestore and sessioncache works in wicket.

---

EDIT

I tested abit and it seems that the pageId didn't count further. The Session class has a method named nextPageId(). This method is called but the pageId is the same. The pageId in the url is always the same. For any reason after the restart of my webserver there is a problem with my Session. It don't counts the pages anymore right.

Answer (score 0):

I can't validate this but maybe this could be the issue.

at step 3 you restart the webserver and load this page from your second pagestore. This page is (re)loaded in the default pagestore with the same id it had because the page already existed so id = 3. You click to go to page 4 but wicket start recounting because of the restart, so page four becomes page 1 (id = 1). next is page gets id = 2 and then you get page id = 3, which already exists in your pagestore. Thing get messy and.. you know.. boom.

If this is your problem than you could build your own IRequestMapper and get rid of the numbers and build your own set. (from a db or something.)

Comment: I recognized, that after the restart my pageIds dont get counted correctly. I always stay on pageId=2. I dont know why.

Comment: I found the error. Thank you for your response. I had an error in my code. I get 2 times the session from the session store. Session instance was then overwritten and I get the same page 2 times. Now it is fixed. It wasn't an error with wicket.